# Path enumeration model, how to get superiors?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the table data below:

```
emp_name VARCHAR(25), path VARCHAR(150)
Albert                /Albert
John                  /Albert/John
Chuck                 /Albert/Chuck
Tom                   /Albert/John/Tom
Frank                 /Frank
```

I want to get a list of superiors of Tom:

```
John
Albert
```

(can include Tom)

Is it possible to do with without splitting the path and then using a sequence table (only way I found)?

DB is Sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE to split the hierarchy string value.

```
declare @T table 
(
  ID int identity,
  emp_name varchar(25),
  [path] varchar(150)
)

insert into @T values
('Albert', 'Albert'),
('John',   'Albert/John'),
('Chuck',  'Albert/Chuck'),
('Tom',    'Albert/John/Tom'),
('Frank',  'Frank')

declare @EmpName varchar(25) = 'Tom'

;with cte(Sort, P1, P2, [path]) as
(
  select 1,
         1,
         charindex('/', [path]+'/', 1),
         [path]
  from @T
  where emp_name = @EmpName  
  union all
  select Sort+1,
         P2+1,
         charindex('/', [path]+'/', C.P2+1),
         [path]
  from cte as C
  where charindex('/', [path]+'/', C.P2+1) > 0
)
select substring([path], P1, P2-P1)
from cte
order by Sort
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
Albert
John
Tom
```

Test the query here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101383/

Another thing you can try

```
select T2.emp_name
from @T as T1
  inner join @T as T2
    on '/'+T1.[path]+'/' like '%/'+T2.emp_name+'/%' and
       T2.emp_name <> @EmpName  
where T1.emp_name = @EmpName
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/101518/get-hierarchy-with-join-using-like

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using a recursive method?

Comment: @user - Sure. As you said using a sequence table. Why don't you want to use a recursive CTE? Does it have performance issues for you? You could also use a string-split function. There are a bundle of them published here on SO.

Comment: Where on SO (link)? I tried to do it using a sequence table only but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: @user - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor